# Dynamically add view to android list?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Hi I have run into a design issue and can't figure out the best approach to take.  Here is a sample of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

When the user clicks on the Plus icon another row will be added below the current condition.  Currently the condition row is in a listview and is setup using a custom adapter.  The left col is filled with the options that the user has chosen from the select columns view.  All that is working but I can't seem to figure out how to add a new row.  So is there a way to dynamically add a new row to the list and fill it with the same data?  OR is there a better alternate way to set this up?

Comment: [Look at this](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html)

Answer (score 1):

So your custom adapter is starting off with three rows?  Then when the user clicks on the plus icon, the `onClick` listener should call a method on your adapter that sets some kind of indication that there are now four rows (after which it calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`).  And your `getView()` method should look at that indicator and if position == 2 (third row) and the indicator is not set, it returns an "Order By" view. If the indicator *is* set, then it should return a "Condition View" and only return an "Order By" view when position == 3 (fourth row).  Does that make sense?

Your adapter reflects the state of your list model at any moment in time.  Any event that occurs where you want to change the `ListView` should update some kind of state in the adapter.  Then `getView()` should always check that current state when returning a view.  So always think in two phases:

1. Your event (like `onClick`) updates some model data in the adapter somewhere.
2. Your adapter's `getView()` method always checks the current model data in the adapter to figure out how to set up the view for the given position.